# WebKitBrowser Control Scroll to Bottom

Tags: .net, user-controls, wysiwyg

I am working on a simple  application using a WebKitBrowser  Control . How do I get the control to automatically scroll to the bottom every time I update the DocumentText of the control? I tried this code but it didn't work

```
WebKitBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: You have a separate method to execute js. I think `WebKitBrowser1.GetScriptManager.EvaluateScript("window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")` will work. Or atleast something similar.

Comment: thank's very much but GetScriptManager is not a member of WebKitBrowser. and there is no similar ScriptManger to try.